# R Shiny - Running a function on user imported data

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I want to create an app which enables user to import their data and to run some function against a user-selected column in the imported data.

For example, I want to run `bartels.rank.test()` on a column in the imported data and want results to be displayed as result in the UI.

How can I do this?

## ui.R

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel(""),
sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv")),
  
  checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
  
  radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
               choices = c(Comma =",",
                           Semicolon = ";",
                           Tab = "\t"),
               selected = ","),
  
  radioButtons("disp", "Display",
               choices = c(Head = "head",
                           All = "all"),
               selected = "head")),

mainPanel(
  tableOutput("contents"),
  textOutput(outputId = "result")
)))
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
require(randtests)
server <- function(input, output) {
output$contents <- renderTable({
req(input$file1)
df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
               header = input$header,
               sep = input$sep,
               quote = input$quote,
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

if(input$disp == "head") {
  return(head(df))
}
else {
  return(df)
}})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:
you add a uiOutput, which is rendered when a file is uploaded and allows the user to select the column with the values used for the test. You then set up a series of reactives in the server to 1. read the dataset, 2. pull out the column names, 3. subset the data based on column name selection and run test. Finally you render the result of the test as text. Note this part will require some changes on your part as the result of the test does not nicely display with text. You could try taking the individual elements of the test result and creating a data.frame from them to display as a table.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),

      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma =",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head"),
      uiOutput('column')),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),
      textOutput(outputId = "result")
    )))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
require(randtests)
server <- function(input, output) {

    read_data <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                   header = input$header,
                   sep = input$sep,
                   quote = input$quote,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }})

  column_names <- reactive({
    names(read_data())
  })

  bartels_rank <- reactive({
    x <- read_data()[[input$column]]
    bartels.rank.test(x, alternative = 'two.sided', pvalue="normal")
    })

  output$column = renderUI({
    selectInput("column", 
                label = "Select column", 
                choices = column_names(),
                selected = column_names()[1])
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    read_data()
  })

  output$result <- renderText({
    bartels_rank() %>% as.character()
  })

  }
```

Comment: Great. Works smoothly. For result, I'm using renderPrint and I'll live with it.